# Do I need to close my HttpClient if I am reusing the connectionPool in it (java)

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is a sample program.

```
public class Foobar {

     private HttpClient;

     public Foobar(RequestConfig config, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, connManager) {
return HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .build();
}

public Foobarrr execute() {
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("/blah");
HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            else if (response.getEntity().getContent() != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                return mapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(), Foobarrr.class);
            }
        catch(Exception ex){
         throw new RuntimeException(ex);


}
```

In the above case, the client is created only once but reused.
I see another version of code in the internet where the httpClient is closed in try-catch. Isn't that an expensive thing or what is the advantage of this over the above way of doing

```
public void executeWithPooledUsingHttpClientBuilder() throws Exception {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                                     .setMaxConnTotal(100)
                                                     .setMaxConnPerRoute(20)
                                                     .build()) {
        final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GET_URL);
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
            EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The latest version of code is absolutely fine.
It is written as per
**The try-with-resources Statement**

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
>   object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all
>   objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

**2.** And this won't cause a performance impact since you are already setting the **connection manager**

```
public Foobar(RequestConfig config, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager) {
return HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .setConnectionManager(connManager)
                .build();
```

> your connection manager is going to have a pool of connections.
>   Hence closing and requesting again won't be a problem.

Comment: HttpClient is closed in the second example I have showed. Closing httpClient, closes connectionManager too. I know about how autocloseable works

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is highly advisable to close `HttpClient` instances once they are not longer needed.

One, however, can use `HttpClientBuilder#setConnectionManagerShared` to inform the builder that it should not wire `HttpClient` to shut down its connection manager when being closed.

Comment: this blog got me confusing..it says HttpClient should be create once per lifetime of web app. My application is a web-service, so the client is always needed. https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Then do you want to re-use HttpClient?

Comment: yes, if it is going to be a performant constraint as mentioned in that blog

Comment: The first rule of Apache HttpClient performance optimization is to re-use HttpClient instances

Comment: Please re-read my answer more carefully this time. One _must_ close HttpClient instances once they are no longer used even when re-using the underlying connection pool. It does not mean one should be creating and closing those instances all the time.